# How to get estimated travel time and distance in flutter

Tags: api, google-maps, flutter, apple-maps

I'm trying to get estimated time and distance between users current location and predefined destination, and I cannot find a way to do this. I know that flutter now has map plugin - [flutter maps](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter) but I do not need to display map, just to use map api to calculate estimated travel time and distance. Something like [MKDirections](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkdirections?language=objc). Am I missing something? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use Google's [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro) and send simple http request to:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json
?units=imperial
&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998
&destinations=40.6905615%2C,-73.9976592
&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

where `origins` are the starting points and destinations are the `ending` points. Replace them with your values.

For the request you could use the package [dio](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio):

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
Dio dio = new Dio();
Response response=await dio.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=40.6905615%2C,-73.9976592&key=YOUR_API_KEY");
print(response.data);
```

Comment: In the REST API way - How we can restrict the API key so that it only be accessed by the Flutter app?